# Cannot unmute sound in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, sound

I have no sound in Ubuntu 12.04.

The sound icon on the top line is OFF (muted). Clicking on SYSTEM SETTINGS and then SOUNDS, just locks up the system settings until I shut down. I tried to watch a Youtube video to check the sound but it freezes up the video. Anything to do with sound just locks up.

I added an older Soundblaster live card that works in Windows but Ubuntu still behaves the same way. I am using a MSI FM2-A75MA motherboard with a AMD A8 5600 APU. I phoned MSI and they say that they don't support Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried everything and are still unhappy, then you obviously know the solution... Occam's Razor: With all else equal, the simplest solution is most likely the correct one. It's obviously your sound card's problem, so buy a new sound card to install on your motherboard. If you need help installing (either physical or software), all of us here on the forum would be more than happy to help! :)
Good luck! :D

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window, run `alsamixer` which has a non-GUI 'curses' interface, [image: picture here],
[Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer) and [Keyboard Commands List](http://alsa.opensrc.org/Alsamixer#KEYBOARD_COMMANDS).

Use the left and right arrow keys to move back and forth. Look for any bars with [MM] at the bottom and move to that bar then press the `m` key to unmute them.